# can i create a moving windows to create a 2D array using weighted average?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, moving-average, weighted-average

i have a 2D vector array and i want to create a new one using a moving window and weight of the values inside the moving window is there any function in numpy or Scipy that does the moving window and create a new value from the old one like in the image

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `scipy.signal.convolve2d` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html . As far as I understand your question you want to do a 2d moving average.

so your w_i_j is your weight kernel (3x3) in `in2` and A is the matrix in `in1` to convolve with.

You just have to decide what to do w/ the boundaries.

I put up some example:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
w = np.array([[.5, .2, .3], [.1, .6, .7], [.2, .9, .6]])
A.shape
Out[6]: (3, 3)
w.shape
Out[7]: (3, 3)
conv = convolve2d(in1=A, in2=w)
conv
Out[9]: 
array([[0.462864  , 0.65447211, 0.7530795 , 0.3966481 , 0.1725783 ],
       [0.32225059, 0.90564724, 1.7780442 , 1.22318628, 0.58611494],
       [0.4547724 , 1.5322374 , 2.36023217, 1.78020784, 0.82436444],
       [0.13660936, 0.77031251, 1.16022925, 1.00877784, 0.48632946],
       [0.0894765 , 0.44799102, 0.50662286, 0.28963816, 0.10239854]])
A
Out[10]: 
array([[0.925728  , 0.93865301, 0.57526099],
       [0.45935558, 0.32894804, 0.61144082],
       [0.44738248, 0.22673391, 0.17066424]])
```

Obviously you get a 5x5 matrix since you can imagine the convolution as moving the 3x3 matrices above each other. When the weight matrix enters it creates the first value in `conv` at position 0,0. The value you mentioned in the picture is approx. 2.36 in the very center of `conv`.

Comment: in fact i have for example 100x100 matrix and i want to use weight according to the distance with a 5x5 moving window actually but it will be probably like this example i m going to try it. and ask for more help.

Comment: yes it's exactly the same. You specify your 5x5 weight kernel. Then you convolve your 100 x 100 matrix with it, the result will be a 104 x 104 matrix. `from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(100, 100)
A.shape
Out[5]: (100, 100)
w = np.random.rand(5, 5)
C = convolve2d(A, w)
C.shape
Out[8]: (104, 104)
D = C[2:102, 2:102]
D.shape
Out[10]: (100, 100)`